# Using Traffic manager, how to mitigate the service unavailability issue caused by TTL

Tags: azure-traffic-manager, azure-application-gateway

I am using traffic manager to load balance our traffic to services hosted on different data center. 
The problem is, when client request to traffic manager, traffic manger response with a IP with TTL setting (say, 5 mins), then client will request to that IP within 5 mins. If the service hosted on that IP down during the 5 mins, the client will get service unavailability error.
What can I do to mitigate this issue? Can application gateway help?

Answer (score 1):

The length of time the Traffic Manager DNS responses are cached for is controlled by the DNS 'TTL' parameter.  You can change this in your Traffic Manager settings--the current minimum is 30 seconds.  More information about how Traffic Manager endpoint failover works is given [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-monitoring/)

Azure Application Gateway provides a proxy-based rather than DNS-based approach to traffic routing, and thus does indeed avoid the issue of DNS caching.  There are various differences between these two approaches, summarized [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-overview/).

Regards,

Jonathan Tuliani, Program Manager, Azure Traffic Manager

Comment: Thanks quick response! From the document [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-overview/), I saw this statement for Application Gateway: idle probe interval 30 secs. Taken out after 5 consecutive live traffic failures or a single probe failure in idle mode. Does this mean the traffic is still possible be routed to a failed endpoint before the failed endpoint is taken out after 5 consecutive failures?